# Passing data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Having a problem understanding what I will call a variable scope question for lack of a better description.

Say I have a page with two functions, `one()` and `two()`. The first function has a locally-scoped variable `x` with an object in it. This function builds an element, below, in the DOM and this element contains an `onClick`, which calls the second function, and needs to pass `x` to the second function as an argument. I.e. the second function needs access to the data that is scoped to the first function.

I have tried:

```
<something onClick="two(x);">
```

but this doesn't seem to work.  I know that there is a way to make `x` global but I have found in my other languages that globally-scoped variables are discouraged as being dangerous.

Comment: show me the coooooooode!

Comment: It would help if you posted some code, we could make suggestions.  You can put var x = 'something' straight into a <script> tag before the functions are defined.  That will make it global, but this is not a great idea if you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml):

```
function one()
{
    var x = Math.random();
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML='Hi!';
    el.addEventListener("click", function(){two(x)}, false); 
    document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(el); 
}
function two(text)
{
    alert(text);
}
one();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfdPb/1/)

Comment: This did indeed work.  This was the kind of pattern I was looking for.  I was a little surprised that more people did not have a standard response for this, as I would think this would be a very common requirement in JavaScript.  This leads me to believe that a lot of people are using globally-scoped variables where they don't have to worry about such things.

Answer (score 1):

Using a global variable within a function is not necessarily bad, but it is considered bad practice to place variables in the window scope, which is assumed if you don’t wrap your variables inside a function or object.

Consider this example:

```
(function() {
  var x = 1;
  function callback() {
    alert(x);
  }
  function bind() {
    x++;
    elem.onclick = callback;
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope).

The function closure of `one()` has access to x. But since it exists in `one()` and not outside other functions will not have access to it. So you are putting `two(x);` in your onClick, which will try to resolve the `x` to a global scope. And there is no global `x`

You can easily fix this by making `x` global. Just place `var x` beside your functions.

Answer (score 0):

to make x global declare it outside of the method

```
var x = 0

function one()

x=1

function two()

print x
```

x will print 1

Comment: You're missing some curly brackets (`{}` and semicolons (`;`). Also, there's no `print` function in javascript (except involving a physical printer). Finally,  the OP knows that `there is a way to make x global` but doesn't want to do that, for good reason.

Comment: this was more pseudo than anything, and he wanted to know how to interchange data between methods, this would work, i might not get points but the knowledge is there